# Ejecutar fragmento de código a una hora/fecha determinada en un script en ejecución

Tags: python, python-3.x

En mi programa (`Python 3.5`) quiero ejecutar una función a una determinada hora independientemente de en que fase del código esté. Pero no conozco ninguna sentencia que verifique todo el tiempo (incluso en el transcurso del programa) que hora es y si es, por ejemplo, las 13:15 ejecutar esa función. Un `while` no serviría porque siempre estaría ejecutando el bucle pero no corriendo el programa. ¿Alguna solución?

Mi SO es Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Agrega información sobre tu sistema operativo. En sistemas *NIX existe un servicio llamado `cron` que ejecuta programas en intervalos planificados. Ignoro si exista algo similar en Windows.

Comment: No me refiero a un programa que se abra a una determinada hora, sino una funcion dentro del codigo que este verificando constantemente si la hora es 13:15, si es asi que ejecute una funcion o un pedazo de codigo

Comment: ¿Debemos entender que el script de python se ejecuta 24/7 y lo que quieres es que cada segundo (por ejemplo) compruebe la hora y si se cumple cierta condición se ejecute una función?

Comment: Efectivamente!.

Comment: Podrias ejecutar esa función en un thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una posible solución es implementar un hilo para ejecutar un temporizador y que ejecute la función cuando se cumpla la condición. De esta forma el hilo principal puede seguir funcionado sin problemas.

Te dejo un ejemplo de implementación. El código tiene comentarios para ir aclarando que se va haciendo y un ejemplo de uso.

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Temporizador(Thread):
    def __init__(self, hora, delay, funcion):
        # El constructor recibe como parámetros:
        ## hora = en un string con formato hh:mm:ss y es la hora a la que queremos que se ejecute la función.
        ## delay = tiempo de espera entre comprobaciones en segundos.
        ## funcion = función a ejecutar.

        super(Temporizador, self).__init__()
        self._estado = True
        self.hora = hora
        self.delay = delay
        self.funcion = funcion

    def stop(self):
        self._estado = False

    def run(self):
        # Pasamos el string a dato tipo datetime
        aux = datetime.strptime(self.hora, '%H:%M:%S')
        # Obtenemos la fecha y hora actuales.
        hora = datetime.now()
        # Sustituimos la hora por la hora a ejecutar la función.
        hora = hora.replace(hour = aux.hour, minute=aux.minute, second=aux.second, microsecond = 0)
        # Comprobamos si la hora ya a pasado o no, si ha pasado sumamos un dia (hoy ya no se ejecutará).
        if hora <= datetime.now():
            hora += timedelta(days=1)
        print('Ejecución automática iniciada')
        print('Proxima ejecución programada el {0} a las {1}'.format(hora.date(),  hora.time()))

        # Iniciamos el ciclo:
        while self._estado:
            # Comparamos la hora actual con la de ejecución y ejecutamos o no la función.
            ## Si se ejecuta sumamos un dia a la fecha objetivo.
            if hora <= datetime.now():
                self.funcion()
                print('Ejecución programada ejecutada el {0} a las {1}'.format(hora.date(),  hora.time()))
                hora += timedelta(days=1)
                print('Próxima ejecución programada el {0} a las {1}'.format(hora.date(),  hora.time()))

            # Esperamos x segundos para volver a ejecutar la comprobación.
            sleep(self.delay)

        #Si usamos el método stop() salimos del ciclo y el hilo terminará.
        else:
             print('Ejecución automática finalizada')


#=========================================================================================
#Ejemplo de uso:

def ejecutar():
    print('Función ejecutada desde hilo')

t = Temporizador('20:42:00',1,ejecutar)# Instanciamos nuestra clase Temporizador
t.start() #Iniciamos el hilo

#Mientras el programa principal puede seguir funcinando:
sleep(2)
for _ in range(10):
    print('Imprimiendo desde hilo principal')
    sleep(2)

# Si en cualquier momento queremos detener el hilo desde la aplicacion simplemete usamos el método stop()
sleep(120) # Simulamos un tiempo de espera durante el cual el programa principal puede seguir funcionando. 
t.stop()   # Detenemos el hilo.
```

Salida del código de prueba:

> Ejecución automática iniciada
>   Proxima ejecución programada el 2016-12-08 a las 20:36:00
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Imprimiendo desde hilo principal
>   Función ejecutada desde hilo
>   Ejecución programada ejecutada el 2016-12-08 a las 20:36:00
>   Próxima ejecución programada el 2016-12-09 a las 20:36:00
>   Ejecución automática finalizada

Dado que el código tiene tantos comentarios y salidas estándar, dejo una versión 'limpia' de el que solo incluye la clase `Temporizador` y sin información por consola del progreso:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Temporizador(Thread):
    def __init__(self, hora, delay, funcion):
        super(Temporizador, self).__init__()
        self._estado = True
        self.hora = hora
        self.delay = delay
        self.funcion = funcion

    def stop(self):
        self._estado = False

    def run(self):
        aux = datetime.strptime(self.hora, '%H:%M:%S')
        hora = datetime.now()
        hora = hora.replace(hour = aux.hour, minute=aux.minute, second=aux.second, microsecond = 0)
        if hora <= datetime.now():
            hora += timedelta(days=1)

        while self._estado:
            if hora <= datetime.now():
                self.funcion()
                hora += timedelta(days=1)
            sleep(self.delay)
```

Mientras esté activo el hilo se ejecutará la función **todos los dias a esa hora** hasta que se detenga usando el método `stop()`. Cuando quieras terminar el programa, usa este método antes para asegurarte que el hilo termina correctamente.

Todos los módulos pertenecen a la biblioteca estándar de `Python` ([datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html), [time](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html), [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html)) y el código funciona sin modificaciones en `Python 2.7` también.

Si necesitas compartir información entre lo que se procesa en el hilo temporizado y tu programa principal usa algún método seguro de comunicación entre hilos, como una cola ([Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html)).

Comment: Esta es una excelente respuesta! En especial la referencia a una posible implementacion de como detener un thread; esto ultimo siendo la unica referencia en SOes.