# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script python a una determinada hora y fecha en Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Necesito ejecutar un script todo los días a las 10:00 en un sistema bajo Windows. ¿Cómo podria hacerlo?. Un ejemplo simple seria que a las 10 se ejecute el script y diga 'hola mundo', o quizás, que el script se ejecute desde el principio pero que cuando llegue las 10:00 lanze 'hola mundo'.

Comment: Robert, indica tu sistema operativo, si es Linux, puedes usar `cron`.

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que deses hacer puedes usar el propio sistema operativo para hacer esto (no especificas cual usas). Es decir usar Task Scheduler en Windows o Cron (UNIX) para que se ejecute el script en el tiempo especificado. Puedes usar algunas librerias externas como [shedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule). La tercera via es crear un proceso en python que se mantenga en ejecución permanente y que llame a su debido tiempo al script, algo similar a esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38195/verificar-todo-el-tiempo/38224#38224) mia a otra pregunta similar.

Comment: es windows intentare con el task, es cierto podria hacer el proceso pero no consumiria muchos recursos , por q estaria comparando la hora por mucho tiempo.. como se usa la libreria shedule

Comment: No tiene porque comparar la hora constantemente (esto si saturaría la cpu), simplemente usas un delay para que se comprube cada x tiempo dependiendo de la precisión requerida. La libreria shedule no la he usado nunca personalmente por lo que habría que mirar la documentación. Usar el programador de tareas en Windows es simple, ahora creo una respuestas para ello.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En Windows que es el SO que usas puedes programar la ejecución periódica del script usando el Programador de Tareas de forma gráfica. Se puede hacer mediante la consola, powershell, archivo bat, etc también si lo deseas.

No se que versión de Windows usas, el ejemplo está probado en Windows 10. Una vez abierto el programador de Tareas (puedes abrirlo de forma rápida pulsando `Tecla Windows + r` y introduciendo `taskschd.msc`) un ejemplo básico sería:

- Nos vamos al menu `Acción` y seleccionamos `Crear tarea...`:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- En la subventana que aparece en la pestaña `General` introducimos el nombre de la tarea (es obligatorio y no puede haber dos tareas con el mismo nombre):

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- En la pestaña `Desencadenadores` hacemos click en `Nuevo`, no aparecerá una nueva subventana donde elegimos a que hora, fecha, periodo, etc se debe ejecutar la tarea, una vez seleccionada damos click en `Aceptar`:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Ahora nos vamos a la pestaña `Acciones` y hacemos click en `Nueva...`. En la  ventana que se abre podemos inttroducir la ruta del script a ejecutar directamente. Esto funcionará si tenemos bién configuradas las variables de entorno (si al hacer doble click sobre un archivo .py se ejecuta direectamente en la CMD). De no ser así o querer usar otro intérprete podemos poner la ruta al intérprete seguida de un espacio y la ruta del script.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Lo anterior es lo básico, se pueden configurar muchas más cosas como que hacer si no se pudo completar la tarea programada(equipo apagado por ejemplo). Puedes ir mirando por las distintas pestañas y ver las opciones que hay. Una vez que todo esté correcto le damos a ceptar y terminamos.

Te dejo un [enlace a la ayuda de Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx) donde se explica esto además de como hacerlo via terminal por si lo prefieres así.

Si lo que quieres es que un script en ejecución al llegar una determinada hora ejecute algún fragmento de código la opción es correr un hilo que compruebe la hora del sistema y lanze esa función cuando se cumpla la condición. Para minimizar la carga del sistema se usa un timer para que no comprube la hora constantemente sino que lo haga cada x segundos, minutos u horas dependiendo de la precisón requerida. Como te comenté en un comentario anterior te dejo el enlace a una pregunta similar donde respondo usando esta idea:

[Ejecutar fragmento de código a una hora/fecha determinada en un script en ejecución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38195/15089)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo , las dos formas funciona !! te lo agradesco