# Como hacer que una función en python se accione todos los días a las 12 de la noche

Tags: python

Necesito que mi función recomendar ()se accione todos los días a las 12 de la noche, es un proyecto en django dónde en una vista aparece la función antes mencionada y necesito que se dispare todos los días a la hora expuesta

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir lo qué has intentado? La comunidad está para ayudar a solventar errores o cómo finalizar algo en concreto no para realizar todo desde 0. Te invito a leer el siguiente enlace de cómo preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask}

Comment: Lanzala desde cron.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Por favor has el [tour], consulta [ask] y luego ve a [edit] tu pregunta. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora. De no ser así, no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor consulta antes de preguntar..
Aqui tienes lo que buscas, ya respondido en este foro: [Enlace a posible solucion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60531/c%C3%B3mo-ejecutar-un-script-python-a-una-determinada-hora-y-fecha-en-windows) Referente a la funcion: Si tienes más de una función y sólo quieres ejecutar esa , crea un main y ponla ahí , así sílo se ejecutará esa.

Comment: Es necesario saver si el SO es windows o Linux, porque de ello depende la solución.

Answer (score 0):

La función tendría que estar en un script con un lazo infinito (`while True`) que este monitoreando la hora del sistema cada cierto tiempo (temporizado con `time.sleep(1)`) con la función `time.localtime()` y cuando llegue a la hora esperada, que realice algún proceso. Todo esto esta disponible en el librería `time`.