# Como hacer que el codigo espere a una hora especifica python todos los dias

Tags: python

Estoy intentando esto

```
if (hora3 == datetime.now().hour) or ((datetime.now().hour == hora2)
or(datetime.now().hour == hora1)):
     root.mainloop()
else:
 #aquí quiero que el codigo se revise o que espere a la hora
```

para que cuando sean las 9 de la mañana el se inicie de paso cualquier cosa que se pueda optimizar por favor avísenme

Comment: ¿No es este un caso prototípico en el que usaríamos un cronjob?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Ger. Es importante que especifiques si quieres que se ejecute un script completo a las 9 horas o que se ejecute parte de un script mientras el resto sigue funcionando. Si es el primer caso usa [Cron](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_(Unix)), si usas un sistema *nix, o el Programador de Tareas en Windows ([¿Cómo ejecutar un script python a una determinada hora y fecha en Windows?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/60531/15089)). En el segundo caso necesitas algo como esto: [Verificar todo el tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38195/15089). Saludos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias FJSevilla tu ayuda fue muy acertada y oportuna la información llenó todas mis expectativas