# como ejecutar una funcion a unahora en especifico en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo ejecutar una funcion de un script en python cada cierta hora.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
import sched
import time

def saludar():
    print("hola")

programador = sched.scheduler()
programador.enterabs(time, 1, saludar())
programador.run()
```

Por ejemplo quiero que se ejecute por ejemplo a las 15:00 y 18:00 horas después de ejecutar el script.

Comment: por lo que e visto eso se ejecuta del sistema operativo no de los lenguajes se llama cron en el caso de windows

Comment: Preguntas relacionadas: [Ejecutar fragmento de código a una hora/fecha determinada en un script en ejecución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38195/15089) y [¿Cómo ejecutar un script python a una determinada hora y fecha en Windows?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/60531/15089). En Linux puedes usar cron.