# Duda ejecución de un archivo py a una determinada hora +

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, beautifulsoup

llevo realizando este programa un par de días, este programa hace un scraping a tiempo real de los componentes del ibex35 con todos sus valores, pues bueno mi duda viene a que me gustaría introducirme como una especie de temporizador o un script con el que a la hora que yo decida poner el programa se ejecute solo y vaya leyendo los valores y cuando una variable, en este caso la hora, cambie en algún parámetro, me envié un correo con un mensaje programado.

Este es el programa:

```html
import smtplib
import requests
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
from time import sleep
data = requests.get('https://www.infobolsa.es/acciones/ibex35')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')           
tabla = soup.find('table', {'class': 'fullTable' })
tbody = tabla.find('tbody')
def prin():
    x=0
    for x in range(x,115):
        for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
            nombre = tr.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()
            precio = tr.find_all('td')[3].text.strip()
            dif = tr.find_all('td')[4].text.strip()
            maximo = tr.find_all('td')[5].text.strip()
            minimo = tr.find_all('td')[6].text.strip()
            renta = tr.find_all('td')[7].text.strip()
            volumen = tr.find_all('td')[8].text.strip()
            efectivo = tr.find_all('td')[9].text.strip()
            hora = tr.find_all('td')[10].text.strip()
            print('%s     -     %s     -     %s      -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s' % (nombre, precio, dif, maximo, minimo, renta, volumen, efectivo, hora))
        time.sleep(300)
prin()
```

Esto último es el bucle que se repetirá 114 veces 1 cada 5 minutos que en total son 9 horas y media que es lo que dura la bolsa de valores, bueno pues quisiera que teniendo el ordenador encendido a las 9 de la mañana se ejecutara solo y cuando la variable (hora) cambiara algun valor me envie un correo con el script de abajo

```
    gmail_user = 'pruebacorreospython@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = '**********'
    sent_from = gmail_user  
    to = ['pruebacorreospython@gmail.com']  
    subject = 'IBEX35'  
    body = "Se ha actualizado la hora del IBEX35" "\n\n- Saludos"
    email_text = """
    Asunto: %s
    %s
    """ % (subject, body)
try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print ('Email sent!')
except:  
    print ('Something went wrong...')
```

Lo siento si algo esta mal puesto o falta pero es mi primer post ^^ Si hay posibilidad de hacerlo me gustaría mucho que me ayudarais con ello!!

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola xPower, te invito a hacer el recorrido inicial (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas como mejorar tu pregunta. De todos modos te dejo esto: **https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38195/ejecutar-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-a-una-hora-fecha-determinada-en-un-script-en-ejecuc**, en donde alguien (con un nombre muy parecido al tuyo) hace una pregunta similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que te refieres a la variable (hora) de tu código. Entonces entiendo que tienes el código que lo dejas ejecutando y se duerme por 300 segundos y hace el scrapeo al despertar. Te sirve algo asi?

```
def prin():
    x=0
    for x in range(x,115):
        for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
            # Otro codigo
            hora = tr.find_all('td')[10].text.strip()
            print('%s     -     %s     -     %s      -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s     -     %s' % (nombre, precio, dif, maximo, minimo, renta, volumen, efectivo, hora))
            return hora          

hora_inicial = prin() # Guardas el primer (hora)
CANT_VECES = 114      # puedes configurarlo para que se ejecute la cantidad de veces deseadas
while CANT_VECES > 0:
    time.sleep(300)       # Esperas 300 segundos
    hora_actual = prin()  # Vuelves a scrapear la pagina
    if hora_inicial != hora_actual:   # Si cambia la (hora)
        # aquí agregas la llamada a funcion de enviar correo 
        hora_inicial = hora_actual    # guardas el nuevo valor
    CANT_VECES -= 1       # descuentas 1 vez de las 114 que quieres se ejecute
```

Comment: Claro, quisiera que a la hora que yo indique se abra solo el archivo y cuando la variable (hora) cambie me envie un correo. Y no entiendo del todo las variables hora_incial y hora_actual.

Comment: Si, la solución que te da user3479487 te permitirá que se ejecute el script a la hora que le configures. Una vez se ejecute el script estará haciendo llamadas cada 5 minutos a la página a scrapear, el valor inicial de (hora) se guardarà en hora_inicial y dentro de 5 minutos cuando vuelva scrapear, si cambia la (hora) ejecute la funcion de enviar el correo y guarda el nuevo valor de hora inicial.

Comment: Ahhh ya entiendo!! perfecto muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Tenes dos opciones

1. Lanzar el script a la hora determinada: Si estas en windows lo
   haces con el Programador de tareas, si estas en linux con crontab
2. Poner el temporizador en el mismo script: podes hacerlo de diversas
   maneras, con alguna librería, usando hilos o algo tan sencillo como
   lo que te pongo a continuación

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

#hora programada
d = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)

#definimos el temporizador
def cron(d):
  while datetime.now()<d:
    sleep(1)

#ejecutamos el temporizador
cron(d)

#acá va el código que querés que se ejecute a la hora indicada
```

Comment: Este último script sirve para windows también? si es así, podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como poner la hora programada? muchas gracias!

Comment: Es independiente del sistema operativo. Tenés que setear los parámetros del datetime que se crea donde dice hora programada